# Sitecore TSQL Script to Query Content Items With a Layout

Tags: t-sql, sitecore

I need to generate a report of all Sitecore content items based on when they were created and include only the ones that have a layout.

I have tried using Sitecore Powershell, but the my Powershell Jedi skills are novice at best, the one script I did get to work takes way to long to execute in a browser window, and it absolutely will not export to CSV, Excel or any other formats (will deal with that later).

My backup plan is to use a TSQL script to query the SQL Databases directly, and so far this is working (my TSQL Jedi Skills are much stronger).  The issue that I am running into is determining, purely using TSQL, how to determine if a Sitecore content item has a layout: can it be rendered as a page, and exclude items such as folders and portlets.

Here is a snippet of my current TSQL script:

```
WITH ItemsTable
AS (
    SELECT CAST('/' + NAME AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ItemPath,
        ID,
        NAME,
        TemplateID,
        MasterID,
        ParentID,
        Created,
        Updated
    FROM dbo.Items AS base
    WHERE (ID = '[REDACTED]')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CAST(parent.ItemPath + '/' + child.NAME AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Expr1,
        child.ID,
        child.NAME,
        child.TemplateID,
        child.MasterID,
        child.ParentID,
        child.Created,
        child.Updated
    FROM ItemsTable AS parent
    INNER JOIN dbo.Items AS child
        ON child.ParentID = parent.ID
    )
SELECT ItemsTable_1.Created,
    ItemsTable_1.NAME,
    ItemsTable_1.ItemPath,
    TemplateItems.NAME AS TemplateName
FROM dbo.Items AS TemplateItems
RIGHT JOIN ItemsTable AS ItemsTable_1
    ON TemplateItems.ID = ItemsTable_1.TemplateID
WHERE (ItemsTable_1.Created >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

Comment: Do you have some DDL or sample data that we can use?

Comment: The closest that I could find to matching on layouts is this:  **<d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}" l="{FCD650A9-A987-45E0-A440-FA2AF58C9BC4}"><r ds="" id="{6EA2F13E-E688-44C3-B498-0CAB632B2C2F}" par="" ph="bodyContentPH" uid="{1FA10A45-54CD-4569-8D28-39F1C2B31191}" /></d>** Anything with the "l" (lowercase L) attribute means that it has a layout.

Comment: This is from the SiteCore SQL SharedFields table

Comment: Try adding this to the Filter clause  `AND CHARINDEX('l="{',<ColumnName>) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

If you go down the Sitecore Powershell route you could try something like this and run it in under a top level node where you content is.

It checks items that were created in the last 30 days and allows you to export them to Excel:

```
get-childitem -recurse | `
        Sort $_."__Created" | `

       Where-Object   {  $_."__Updated" -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) }    |

        Show-ListView -property Name, `
        @{Label="Created Date"; Expression={$_."Created"}}, `
        @{Label="Last Updated By"; Expression={ $_."__Updated By" } } `
        -Modal -Width 690 -Height 600 -PageSize 200
    Show-Result -Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, but I found a work around.  The chief problem was that the export to CSV, Excel, etc. function for the Show-ListView option is not working on our Sitecore instance (to be addressed separately).  Also, the scripts were running dog slow - the amount of results returned was not the issue; it would not export even if one one result was returned.

As I learned more about SiteCore and Powershell, I figured out how to export to CSV directly without using Show-ListView.

This was for a high-priority report that needed to be generated and TSQL at the time was the most expedient option.